# How to handle properly UIButton properties and spaces between multiple lines

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I use Xcode 7, Swift, and storyboard part to create a button with 2 lines.
The two lines are centered but I can't add space between them (like paragraph spacing ?).

The button is now like this :

[image: Button without space between lines]

I used the storyboard approach with combining modifications in the code.
Here is the ViewController.swift code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var boutonAfficher: UIButton!

    @IBAction func afficheNombres() {
        boutonAfficher.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
       // some other actions after
    }

    @IBAction func TouchDownBoutonAfficher() {
        boutonAfficher.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        boutonAfficher.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        boutonAfficher.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        // What to add here to add space between lines ? ParagraphStyle ?
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


}
```

In the Main.storyboard, I put one UIButton and I've done the following actions :

- link the button (New referencing Outlet) to **boutonAfficher**
- link the button (Touch Down) to **TouchDownBoutonAfficher**
- link the button (Touch Up Inside) to **afficheNombres**
- also added this through Identity Inspector :

[image: Properties]

So, my questions are :

- How to add the space between the two lines ?
- Is there a clean/easy way to create this button (round corners, two lines, with border) without mixing storyboard objects and code ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To your first question,  you try the "\n" in your button title, maybe this is simplest method. Your second question, I want to know too :-)

Comment: Yes, I could add a blank line also, but wondering how to do it in a proper way (how skilled coders do this). So we're 2 to wait :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the title property of your UIButton to  **attributed** from **plain** and then change the line spacing property.

[image: Output of your button title]

[image: Change the line spacing (5 in my case)]

Comment: Thank you, it's easy to use it when you know how to proceed. It solved my immediate problem :-)